# Read very large SPSS file with special characters into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, spss

I have an SPSS (.sav) file with over 90,000 columns and around 1800 rows. Previously I have used the code below (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181147/performance-reading-large-spss-file-in-pandas-dataframe-on-windows-7-x64)), which has worked well.

```
raw_data = spss.SavReader('largefile.sav', returnHeader = True)
raw_data_list = list(raw_data)
data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data_list)
data = data.rename(columns=data.loc[0]).iloc[1:]
```

However, now some of the columns contain special characters (including Chinese characters and accented characters). Using the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/savReaderWriter/index.html), it appears using `ioUtf8=True` with `SavReader` should achieve what I'm aiming to do. So I do the following:

```
raw_data = spss.SavReader('largefile.sav', returnHeader = True, ioUtf8=True)
raw_data_list = list(raw_data)
data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data_list)
data = data.rename(columns=data.loc[0]).iloc[1:]
```

Line 1 runs fine, but line 2 returns the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 6: invalid continuation byte
```

How can I get around the problem?

Comment: Something similar happens to me when my non-Latin characters are truncated. Are you sure you have your texts in full-length ? Try to load parts of your data, see where it breaks (which line and column)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are characters encoded in your dataset that cant be decoded with UTF-8. Namely an "á" encoded with latin-1.

```
c = 'à'

print c.decode('utf-8')

>>> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: unexpected end of data

print c.decode('latin-1')

>>> à
```

you could try to save your dataset in unicode format, in case it is not unicode already (make a backup before you do this, just in case). Try the following: Open SPSS without data open, type

```
set unicode on.
```

open your dataset and save it. It should now be in unicode format. Now try and run your code to import the data.

*** Update

You could try to read your file row by row and handle the errors as they come in:

```
rawdata = []
with SavReader('largefile.sav', ioUtf8=True) as reader:
    for record in reader:
        try:
            rawdata.append(record)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            r = record.decode('latin-1')
            rawdata.append(r.encode('utf-8'))                
 data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data_list)
 data = data.rename(columns=data.loc[0]).iloc[1:]
```

Because you have Chinese characters as well you might have to add another `try:` `except:` block for that if adding them to your rawdata list raises an error too.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I still get the same error. I tested if the dataset was already in the unicode format using `SHOW UNICODE` before doing `set unicode on.` and it was. Do you have any suggestions for how I can dig deeper?

Comment: I updated my answer. If that doesnt work, Im out of ideas

Comment: Thanks for your updated suggestion but now I'm getting a `UnicodeDecodeError` on the `for record in reader` line, screenshot [here](https://imgur.com/FynaQzO). This seems against what is suggested in the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/savReaderWriter/index.html), under the **Reading a file in unicode mode (default in SPSS v21 and up)** subtitle so I will try to log an issue somewhere